Issuer of access token from ADFS cannot be validated
I'm building an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API that uses ADFS for authentication (i.e. the API is a resource being secured by ADFS).
I am able to obtain access tokens with a valid signature from ADFS but validation of the issuer fails in my API with the following message:
www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="The issuer 'http://my-adfs-server/adfs/services/trust' is invalid" 

Note that the issuer address is specified in the token with an http address (rather than https):
http://my-adfs-server/adfs/services/trust

Everything works fine if I disable issuer validation as follows:
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuer = false
};

But obviously, this is not a viable solution. I need to figure out why the validation fails.
I wonder if the problem could be that the issuer address is specified with http rather than https? All communication with ADFS (including requests for tokens) uses https.
I wonder if anyone could explain how ASP.NET Core determines if a token issuer address is valid or not - and if the http address might be the problem?
Edit:
The same issuer URL (also using http) is specified in  /.well-known/openid-configuration:
"access_token_issuer": "http://my-adfs-server/adfs/services/trust"

So validation must do more than just comparing this URL to the one found in the token.

Have you tried directly configuring ValidIssuer / ValidIssuers on TokenValidationParameters? It is quite possible that it is the http vs https if you configured the authority/metadata URL with HTTPS. ASP.NET Core uses the issuer from the metadata it downloads at startup.

@juunas I did try adding the URL to the ValidIssuers array without any luck. I have not configured the metadata URL though, only the authority. Could this be an issue?

Authority configures the metadata URL indirectly. Essentially it takes your authority and adds a predefined suffix to it; something like this: http://my-adfs-server/adfs/services/trust/.well-known/openid-configuration (if the issuer you mentioned was the authority). Usually you don't need to configure the metadata URL, authority is enough.

@juunas Setting ValidIssuer during startup also has no effect. Also, note that the URL in the token and the open ID configuration actually do match (see the edit above).

Is there an "issuer" property in the openid-configuration?

Yes, issuer is https://my-adfs-server/adfs.

Ok, so without configuring ValidIssuer manually, it would certainly be wrong, as the metadata specifies it with https but the token contains http. Not sure why it doesn't work if you specify the ValidIssuer though :\
